# Submit app on AppStore without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submit, provisioning-profile

How can I submit application on appstore without Xcode?

I do have Xcode but my client doesn't. I know he can get application loader and submit but I'm not sure what do I have to send him to load with application loader.

I found other answers on stackoverflow but I'm not sure how to work it out with my clients certificates/provisions. Since I set them in Xcode how can I set his provision profile?

If someone could provide full description on how to work it out with my Xcode and clients certificates/provision profiles.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can do this if your client have mac or apple laptop

Comment: tell your client to download the application loader and install it and you send him ipa file of distribution type (for this it required mac)

Comment: I do have mac and xcode and I've sent him already ipa's for testing with adhoc provisions I made but what provision should I enter now for submit to store? Should it be his provision?

Comment: build you project with distribution type provisining profile

Comment: So not any specific just one saying "Distribution" (prolly automatic)? But when creating ipa I'm required to selected provision to sign with...

Comment: automatic will be fine...

Comment: after(archiving) you will get orgineser opened with diffrent buttons "validate" and "distribute"

Comment: I go distribute and then after 1-2 steps I have to choose provision to sign with... I only have mines from my developer account.

Comment: click on distribution button and you will get drop down menu select the save for enterprise..... and press next you will get your ipa file of distribution type .send this ipa file to client to appload it with application loader ..rest all

Comment: oo for making distribution type provising profile fist ask the client to provide its details or if not then tell him to create it

Comment: You dont have option "Choose profile to sign in" after selecting enterprise? Wich loads all provision profiles from my developer account. Shouldnt I enter his?

Comment: Ohh, so I load his provision in my xcode and then do following steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Archive your project with certificates you use for Appstore distribution
2. Click Distribute
3. Select save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment
4. Save .ipa file and send him an ipa file

Comment: He has to send me his provisions so I selected them after clicking distribute or?

Comment: Yes - distribution provisioning profile for bundle id you have there.